# How to generate random numbers in async rust?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

The `rng` crate is neither `Sync` nor `Send`, so the rng::thread_rng can not cross the .await point. What is the simplest and beautiful way to generate random numbers in async rust?

Generating A lot of numbers beforehead and then use them is ugly.

Comment: Confusingly, the handle returned by `thread_rng` seems to compile being transferred across await [in this playground example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=10c50d45cbeecbc2f28133e776a10fa0). I'm not sure what's up with that.

Comment: But you could always create your own proper rng, e.g. using `let mut rng: StdRng = SeedableRng::from_entropy()`, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65053773/1600898). That will give you something that is not just a handle to a thread-local and should be Send+Sync.

Comment: @user4815162342 thanks for the answer. I used StdRng in an async tokio stream and it works flawless.

Comment: @DanielLeiszen Glad it helped. To answer my own question from the first comment, awaiting a non-send future works in `main()` because main itself gets run in the main thread, which is why Tokio can get away with not requiring that the future it produces be `Send`. However, if you try something like `tokio::spawn(async { foo().await })`, it will fail to compile, as expected.

Answer (score 8):

From the tokio Discord server

```
let random = rand::random::<i64>();
```

or

```
let random = {
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    rng.gen::<i64>()
}
```

"make sure the rng variable falls out of scope before you use an await"

Answer (score 1):

Getting a new rng handle is cheap. A rng will be created once per thread (when used), and after that `ThreadRng::default` only uses [LocalKey::with](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/struct.LocalKey.html) and Rc::clone. Do you need to keep the previous state so the number sequence is repeatable?